# Kitten very nervous and lack of energy

Tags: cats, fleas

I got 2 female (same litter) kittens (7 weeks old) about 6 months ago. They were both healthy and showed no signs of problems. I also have 2 male cats (about 6 years old, both castrated and friendly towards the kittens). All 4 cats are house cats and rarely leave the house. If they do then they sit in the yard and never wander away. As I said, both male cats have been castrated but the female kittens have yet to be spayed.

About 2 months ago I noticed fleas so I bought some Frontline flea control and have been using it for the past 2 months (2 treatments so far).

Since then I have noticed one of the kittens has deteriorated in health. She has scabs on the back of her neck (probably due to scratching). This isn't a major concern as I have read that this can happen. To be clear, I am not sure if this deterioration is due to the fleas or not.

Last month we had to take one of the kittens (Kimi for clarification) to the vets. She was very dehydrated and weak. She was also vomiting a lot. Since we couldn't afford the bill for further checks, the vet gave her a some fluids under the skin.

She was fine for a while after that but now seems to be back to the same. She hasn't vomited at all but is very weak. She has always been a cat who likes her cuddles, but recently has done nothing but that. She rarely gets up and sometimes I have to bring her food to her. She will seek out places which she can go under, such as the bed covers or my wife's dressing gown. The only way she will move is if she is coerced or she smells food.

She appears to be very nervous and shaky. Her breathing is faster than usual and her head appears to dart around whenever she hears or feels something near her.

She is also very unstable on her legs. It seems to affect her back legs. Sometimes she will walk sideways due to it. She sometimes loses bladder control too. Several times she has squatted in the living room and done her business and several times she has done this on our bed (it appears as if she doesn't realise it at the time).

Has anyone had something similar happen or know why this is happening?

All 4 cats are being treated with Frontline pipettes for their fleas. The other 3 cats are fine with this. I am not suggesting this is due to the flea treatment, just mentioning in case it is important.

Comment: Go to your vet! Don't focus on the flea treatment, that might be part of the problem or what started it, but now your kitten needs help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your kitten is very sick.** There are a variety of problems that can cause these symptoms, from a tick bite to a spinal injury, but we cannot diagnose these problems over the internet. The only way for your kitten to get help is to go see a veterinarian.

Comment: Thanks. Appointment for vets is already booked. Just wanted to see if anyone had any ideas before then.